# how to find target branch name using git commands

Tags: git, git-branch

i have the following structure

development --- > FOO (branch name)

Now, my current branch is FOO .

How to get parent branch (development) using git commands.

I don't want to use contains because If i have FOO branch name in master also so it will show wrong result in my case

Comment: I don't want to use contains because If i have FOO branch name in master also so it will show wrong result in my case